# Is there any way to get recently inserted value in a table without using aggregate functions?

Tags: mysql

I tried to get the users list who are all accessed our application in past 6 months . In our table , we are storing login_time , user_id ..etc . It's a huge table approximately it will contain over 3 million rows . We splitted up every month tables as like below format `TABLE_MONTH_YEAR` . I am running this query in current month table only .

I tried this query .

```
select max(login_time) , user_id from ZmediaUserDetails group by user_id
```

`user_id` is an indexed column .

`login_time` is an  timestamp .

I am running this query in production setup with master/slave setup . I ran this query in a slave machine . I waited for nearly a hour . Still it was not finished. I checked the slave status using `show slave status` it shows `Seconds_Behind_Master: 4886` . So I killed that query .

I can't create an index in either master or slave . Because , It will lock the whole table .

Please give your suggestions .

Comment: Use EXPLAIN for some insight into how MySQL is processing your query. Locking isn't a sufficient reason to avoid creating a necessary index. It doesn't take *that* long to index one column of 3 million rows. One alternative is to dump the database to a file, and load it onto a different machine. Build the index and run your report.

Comment: Creating an index on an integer field (I assume timestamp is managed as an integer) takes about two minutes (maybe less) on a low end machine with such a table size. You should reconsider this option.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you running ???

Comment: ZmediaUserDetails is a table or view?

Comment: An index on `(user_id, login_time)` would make this specific query much faster.

Comment: @neo ZmediaUserDetails is an table

Comment: This has been cross-posted on SO -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14362082/is-there-any-way-to-get-recently-inserted-value-in-a-table-without-using-aggrega

Comment: @bluefeet First I posted on stack overflow. People suggested to post it on dba.

Answer (score 2):

Your existing index doesn't help you out at all, since you are actually asking for the last timestamp of every possible user. This means the only way for MySQL to answer this is to do a full table scan.

As @ypercube commented, an index on `(user_id, login_time)` is good for this kind of query - MySQL could utilize such an index without actually going to the table.

Adding an index to a table will indeed lock the table; but there are solutions to that as well. Take a look at [oak-online-alter-table](http://openarkkit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/openarkkit/doc/html/oak-online-alter-table.html) or [pt-online-schema-change](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-online-schema-change.html) (disclaimer: I'm author of the first), both of which are scripts which allow online table alteration via simulation, triggers and incremental copy.

You might also want to solve this in a completely different way: create a new table like

```
CREATE TABLE last_user_login_time (
  user_id INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY, 
  last_login_time DATETIME
);
```

And

```
INSERT INTO last_user_login_time 
  VALUES (the_user_id, NOW()) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE last_login_time=NOW()
```

to this table upon any new login. Thus, keeping the last login time per user at any given time. This means more writes (an additional write per login), but I suspect this table should be very small and the impact proportionally small. Reading from it, of course, is trivial.